# Questions "for chapter" or "to chapter"?

Tags: to-for

I always have a hard time in these cases: to choose **for** or **to**. Suppose I want to make a list of questions and as a headline I would like to name it something like: Questions for chapter 2. Is that correct? I think it sounds correct but the following I am less certain about. Is the following sentence correct:

*"If you keep on reading, you will find the questions to chapter 2 in the book"*.

I could use the longer version:

*"If you keep on reading, you will find the questions related to chapter 2 in the book"*. Which I am almost certain is correct with respect to *to* and *for*. But I would like to write as short as possible, please help me out.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified by construction, complementizer, or verbal government -- which is not the case here -- _for_ means 'for the purpose or benefit of' and _to_ means 'directed towards'. Which one seems more appropriate here?

Comment: Then I would say **to** is the correct one here.

Comment: Then you're using "directed" metaphorically. If that's clear to the students, cool. But "benefit" may be more welcome.

Comment: I don't understand why "benefit" would be more welcome?

Comment: Ah man, now I think *for* is the better option. This is not easy for me :( english is like my third language.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard. I'm lucky English is my first, but I wish there had been more languages around when I was young. I'm currently trying to learn pidgin Hindi for travelling to a wedding in Jaipur, and, like I said, it's hard.

Comment: Questions ***on*** chapter 2?

Answer (score 1):

Among the many meanings of "for" is this: Used to indicate correlation or correspondence (source: *Am. Her. Dict. 4e*, def. 4b.), which seems to fit the example. My ear says "for" as well. "Questions to chapter 2" isn't idiomatic, at least not in the U.S.